# Selenium Webdriver: How to verify a text that is within h2 and duplicated class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to locate the **Text** within the below HTML code but there are two duplicated classes.

```
<div id="header" class="cf">
<div class="cf">
<h1>
   <a href="/">Text</a>
</h1>
```

I  located but not sure if that is the best way to do it because the text might `appear some where else.

```
WebElement LL = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Text"));
```

Anyone have a better way to locate this please? THANK you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go by the following css to identify the element more precisely. And, the id `header` should be unique and that should be enough to uniquely identify this element

```
By css = By.cssSelector("#header div.cf>h1>a");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(css );
String text = element.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath as your selector and then use WebElements `getText()` method to extract the text.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='cf']/h1/a"));
String text = element.getText();
```